# not possible run windows from other this after install grub

Tags: grub, grub2, boot-loader

I have this disks

```
sudo fdisk -l
[sudo] password for grek: 
Disk /dev/loop0: 91.69 MiB, 96141312 bytes, 187776 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 63.28 MiB, 66355200 bytes, 129600 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop2: 4 KiB, 4096 bytes, 8 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop3: 346.33 MiB, 363151360 bytes, 709280 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop4: 240.61 MiB, 252301312 bytes, 492776 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop5: 49.84 MiB, 52260864 bytes, 102072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop6: 73.85 MiB, 77438976 bytes, 151248 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop7: 466.54 MiB, 489201664 bytes, 955472 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 465.76 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Disk model: WDC  WDS500G2B0A
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: AE7B31F8-73AF-4BF3-AA33-EA439B3F3678

Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048    206847    204800   100M EFI System
/dev/sda2     206848    239615     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda3     239616 975728749 975489134 465.1G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda4  975730688 976771071   1040384   508M Windows recovery environment


Disk /dev/sdb: 931.51 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: WDC WD10EZEX-08W
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xd7c84f4f

Device     Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *          2048    1026047    1024000   500M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb2          1026048 1561205735 1560179688   744G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb3       1951834112 1953519615    1685504   823M 27 Hidden NTFS WinRE
/dev/sdb4       1561206782 1951832063  390625282 186.3G  5 Extended
/dev/sdb5       1561206784 1951832063  390625280 186.3G 83 Linux

Partition 4 does not start on physical sector boundary.
Partition table entries are not in disk order.


Disk /dev/sdc: 223.57 GiB, 240057409536 bytes, 468862128 sectors
Disk model: PNY CS900 240GB 
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xdae90987

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1  *         2048   1187839   1185792   579M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdc2         1187840 467779754 466591915 222.5G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdc3       467781632 468856831   1075200   525M 27 Hidden NTFS WinRE


Disk /dev/loop8: 174.21 MiB, 182677504 bytes, 356792 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

eailer i have windows boot manager it has 2 windows , one broken, second working.

I install ubuntu - have hope that he install grup and it grub i can select linux / windows on disk x , windows on disk y

but i get :
linux
windows boot loader

when i select win boot loader he try repair (with fail) and way that work before install ubuntu.  -> run windows from other disk , after click it run. but now is back to grub,

how i can fix this ?

i try boot-repair , grub customizer - but there is no option run windows on disk x, only win boot loader that dont work,,,